# Sending data to server flask html

Tags: python, html, flask

I am trying to create a simple checkbox that sends the data to server here is my html code.

```
<form action="." method="POST">
<div class="checksheet">

    <input id="XML Parser" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>XML Parser
    <input id="Feed Parser" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>Feed Parser
    <input id="Text Parser" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>Text Parser
    <input id="Case Normalization" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>Case Normalization
    <input id="Stemmer" class="checkbox" type="checkbox"/>  Stemmer

</div>

<div class="submit"><input type="submit"  value="Send" name="raw_text"></div>
</form>
```

What I am trying to do is very similar to the question asked here: [Send Data from a textbox into Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277933/send-data-from-a-textbox-into-flask?rq=1)
But except with the text box.. I have checkboxes.

But  I get this error:

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on the server.

If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

MY server side code (in flask) is:

```
@app.route('/raw_text.html')
def home ():
    file = "sample.xml"
    contents = open(file).read()

    contents = contents.decode('utf-8')
    return render_template('raw_text.html',  contents=contents,file=file)

@app.route('/raw_text.html',methods=['POST'])
def get_data():
    print "REQUEST ",request.form()
    data = request.form['raw_text']
    print data
    return "Processed"
```

Any suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

1. Your checkbox elements need a `name` attribute, this is what is used when the data is sent to the back end. Each checkbox that is related to each other needs to have the same `name`.
2. Your `action` attribute needs to point to a URL. If you are posting it to the same page as the form, you can remove the attribute.
3. `ID`'s cannot contain spaces.
4. To be accessible the check boxes need `<label>`s,

Comment: @Fraz I clarifed Burhan's answer, hopefully it will be approved