# Flask POST request returning to main webpage instead of returning result

Tags: python, flask

I want to write a view that asks for some input then returns it as uppercase. I followed the instructions in [Send Data from a textbox into Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277933/send-data-from-a-textbox-into-flask/12278642#12278642).

The app is hosted using Phusion Passenger via cPanel at `example.com/form`. When I click <kbd>Submit</kbd>, I am sent to `example.com`. Nothing happens to the text on `example.com/form` before I am redirected.

What am I doing wrong? Why am I being redirected?

`templates/form.html`

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    <textarea name="text"></textarea>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

`form.py`

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template('form.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def form_post():
    return request.form['text'].upper()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both the answers you followed had an issue for apps that aren't hosted at the root. (They've been edited now.)

Your app is hosted at `/form`. A form's `action` should be an absolute path, not a relative path. Always use `url_for` to generate URLs and you'll avoid this issue.

```html
<form action="{{ url_for('form_post') }}" method=post>
```

Since your two views share the same URL, the `action` can be omitted. A common pattern in this case is to use one view to handle GET and POST.

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return request.form['text'].upper()

    return render_template('index.html')
```