# How to take input and output from html to python script

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

I'm making  a python code and using flask to make a webpage.I need to take input from this html page into python and after processing sending back to html page.How I can do so ?

> `Blockquote
>       from flask import Flask, render_template

```
  app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route('/')

  def  home():
       return render_template("login.html")


  @app.route('/about/')

  def  about():
       return ('you wil get all sort of shayari here')

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run() 
                  '
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send data from a textbox into Flask?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277933/send-data-from-a-textbox-into-flask)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same within a single view. Assume if you want to register user you can do something like this.

```
 @app.route("/register_user", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    def register_user():
        """Register user."""
        form = SomeForm() 
        # treat POST request 
        if form.validate_on_submit():
           # do something ... 
           # return redirect ... 


        # else response to GET request
        # return render_template...
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I'm very new into programming world, basically I'm a network designer so logically I can underrstand the code. But few question's :-1 SomeForm is a function in which we can define validation process ? 2. how to put post and get request.

Comment: Go ahead... Ask the questions what you are facing doubts in.

Comment: @Ankit you can add get/post code separately like `if request.method == 'GET/POST'`